# fluentd config to pick up jenkins docker logs

Tags: jenkins, fluentd, fluent-docker

I have a jenkins pod that emits log in this format:

```
2021-03-07 10:38:23.873+0000 [id=9370]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Fingerprint cleanup. 3 ms
2021-03-07 17:56:02.812+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started Download metadata
2021-03-07 17:56:02.820+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
2021-03-07 17:56:13.405+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
2021-03-07 17:56:13.678+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Ant.AntInstaller
2021-03-07 17:56:14.188+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstaller
2021-03-07 17:56:15.458+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
2021-03-07 17:56:15.459+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1
2021-03-07 17:56:15.461+0000 [id=9857]  INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Download metadata. 12,643 ms
2021-03-07 20:59:17.933+0000 [id=10070] INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started telemetry collection
2021-03-07 20:59:17.947+0000 [id=10070] INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished telemetry collection. 4 ms
```

I am struggling with the fluentd forwarder config to pick up this log.

```
 <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/jenkins*.log
      pos_file /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-jenkins.log.pos
      tag jenkins
      **< Qn: How should I be writing the log parser statement>**
      read_from_head true
  </source>
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: How did you test it? You can test with `none` under `<parse>` section. Docs: https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#less-than-parse-greater-than-directive-required

Comment: https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/none

Comment: @Azeem from the docs, none is for single as-is field.

Comment: Aren't you trying to send the logs as-is?